# xmlserializer for custom object

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

Here is how my xml file looks like:

I tried to use xsd to generate class for my object but somehow it didn't work when I tried to deserialize it. I need columns to be an string array, what should my class(object) be so that it can deserialize the xml.

```
<ArrayOfDirective>  
<Directive>
<TestCaseName>RunSqlCar</TestCaseName>
<Action>IgnoreColumn</Action>
<Columns>
<ColumnName>value1</ColumnName>
<ColulmnName>value2</ColulmnName>
</Columns>
<Description>These columns never match becuase IDs are different always.</Description>    
</Directive>
</ArrayOfDirective>
```

Error:
Error reading c:\Directives.xml:  There is an error in XML document (2, 2)

Comment: Please edit your question instead of commenting on it.

Comment: It's correct what I have in the question. First I thought I missed to add that part.

Comment: Do you guys want to see the xsd generated class?

Comment: `but somehow it didn't work` What didn't work? what error did you get?

Comment: it threw me an exception....."There is an error in the xml file".

Comment: You are missing a closing tag for ArrayOfDirective

Comment: I have it in the original file..........somehow missed it here

Comment: `it threw me an exception....."There is an error in the xml file"` then see the inner exception. What does it say? Is It really so hard to read what an exception says to you? It generally says the line & column number where the exception occured.

Answer (score 0):

Your data, serialized using XmlSerializer, will look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfDirective xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Directives>
    <Directive>
      <TestCaseName>RunSqlCar</TestCaseName>
      <Action>IgnoreColumn</Action>
      <Columns>
        <Column>
          <ColumnName>value1</ColumnName>
        </Column>
        <Column>
          <ColumnName>value2</ColumnName>
        </Column>
      </Columns>
      <Description>These columns never match because IDs are different always.</Description>
    </Directive>
  </Directives>
</ArrayOfDirective>
```

These are the example classes that were serialized to the above XML.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ArrayOfDirective directives = new ArrayOfDirective();

        Directive directive = new Directive("RunSqlCar", "IgnoreColumn",
                "These columns never match because IDs are different always.");

        directive.Columns.Add(new Column("value1"));
        directive.Columns.Add(new Column("value2"));

        directives.Directives.Add(directive);

        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ArrayOfDirective));
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText("c:\\directives_generated.xml"))
        {
            ser.Serialize(sw, directives);
        }
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class ArrayOfDirective
{
    public List<Directive> Directives { get; set; }

    public ArrayOfDirective()
    {
        Directives = new List<Directive>();
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class Directive
{
    public string TestCaseName { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public List<Column> Columns { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public Directive(string testCaseName, string action, string description)
    {
        TestCaseName = testCaseName;
        Action = action;
        Description = description;
        Columns = new List<Column>();
    }

    public Directive()
    {
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class Column
{
    public string ColumnName { get; set; }

    public Column(string columnName)
    {
        ColumnName = columnName;
    }

    public Column()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont want to generate the xml file but instead read the xml into a list of objects using XMLserializer.deserialize